# Compare set of objects and get the latest one

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a collection of objects and I want to have a method that picks the latest one by comparing the creation date:

```
public function getCoverImage(){
    foreach($this->getImages() as $image){

    }
}
```

I can access date with

```
$image->getCreatedAt()
```

and it will return an DateTime object. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$chosen = NULL;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if ($chosen === NULL || ($chosen->getCreatedAt() < $image->getCreatedAt()) ) {
        $chosen = $image;
    }
}
```